# Limit of $F( Log( G(x) ) )$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Is their any common way or effective way to calculate limit of an equation with logarithm functions inside?
For example:

1. $$\lim_{x \to \infty} (4-3x)\log\left(\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right)$$
2. $$\lim_{x \to \infty} x \log\left(\sin\left(\frac1x\right)+\cos\left(\frac1x\right)\right)$$
   I found a hint that using series expansion.

The first example can be expanded to : $3-\frac{17}{2x}+\frac{13}{x^2}-\frac{247}{12 x^3}+\frac{168}{5x^4}$

The second one can be expanded to : $1-\frac1x+\frac{2}{3 x^2}-\frac{2}{3x^3}+\frac{2}{3 x^4}$

Is it true? How can we do that ?

Thanks for reading the question.
Any help is appreciated !

Comment: If you have been able to build the series by yourself, all my congratulations. There are exact. Taylor expansion is, from very far away, my prefered way for solving limits. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need L'Hospital for the first one. Clearly $\frac{x+1}{x+2} \to_{x \to \infty} 1$, hence $\log \big(\frac{x+1}{x+2} \big) \to_{x \to \infty} 0$. now expand the brackets, an the first term (with $4$ in the front) converges to 0, so you are left with
$$
-3x \log \bigg(\frac{x+1}{x+2} \bigg)=-3 \log \bigg(\frac{x+1}{x+2} \bigg)^x  =-3 \log \bigg(\frac{x+2-1}{x+2} \bigg)^{x+2-2} \\
= -3\bigg(1-\frac{1}{x+2}\bigg)^{x+2}\cdot\bigg(1-\frac{1}{x+2}\bigg)^{-2}
$$
Now take the limit. The result is $-3 e^{-1}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** for the first:
$$(4-3x)\log\Bigl(\frac{x+1}{x+2}\Bigr)=\frac{\log(x+1)-\log(x+2)}{(4-3x)^{-1}}\ .$$
Now use L'Hopital's rule.  The second question can be done in a similar way.  You might be able to do them by constructing series but I doubt it would be any easier than this method.